# How to install setuptools in location Python compile?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a Python version in a local directory, in order to avoid interference with the general Python on a CentOS 6.3 host, and Python configure and make went fine.  In this Python I need to install an additional module (`Jinja2`), but this requires `setuptools` to install.

Based on `setuptools` source in "../" I did:

```
Python-3.4.2> tar -xzf ../setuptools-12.2.tar.gz 
Python-3.4.2> cd setuptools-12.2/
Python-3.4.2/setuptools-12.2> ../python setup.py install
```

But this gives and error message with:

```
error: can't create or remove files in install directory
...
The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, 
or the distutils default setting) was:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/
```

It appears that `--install-dir` is not available for `setup.py install`, but I also tried e.g. `--install-lib` but I can't make it work without errors.

How is it possible to install `setuptools` in a local Python build ?

Is there a general way to make Python additions apply to the Python installation for the `python` call, instead of attempting to change an unrelated Python installation ?

---

**Addition related to `pip`**

I also tried installing `pip` using:

```
Python-3.4.2 > ./python ../get-pip.py
```

But this also gave an error message related to attempting install for a general Python version, and not the local one I have build:

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip

  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4'
```

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using pip? You need to read up on [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)). It does exactly what you're trying to do with about 200x less hassle.

Comment: Initially I wanted to base installation on source files, to have control over the version installed, but after hours of trying I am willing to accept pip, but I could not make that work either.

Comment: You can `pip install program==x.y.z` where x.y.z is the version number as long as that version is on PyPi.

Comment: Please see my addition related to `pip`; I was not able to make this work either.

Comment: That's because you're still not using virtualenv's correctly. You're trying to install in a root owned directory so you either have to use `sudo` with pip or use a virtualenv somewhere in your user's domain as I originally suggested.

Comment: Thanks, I made it work with virtualenv after I read the Python description at [venv — Creation of virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).